# How to sort this output in text?

Tags: linux, bash

I am using below command to get some data. Now I want it to be sorted on the basis of field after ",".

```
[im@vas_db1 processed]$ cat tps_info.edr.2018-01-15* | grep IM_SYS_TPS | cut -d ","  -f 1,4 | head
2018-01-15 00:00:00,32
2018-01-15 00:00:01,32
2018-01-15 00:00:02,27
2018-01-15 00:00:03,41
2018-01-15 00:00:04,41
2018-01-15 00:00:05,24
2018-01-15 00:00:06,29
2018-01-15 00:00:07,55
2018-01-15 00:00:08,35
2018-01-15 00:00:09,21
```

Comment: `... | sort -t, -k2`

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `sort`:

```
sort -t"," -k2 your_file
```

Or in your case, pipe it:

```
[ .. ] | sort -t"," -k2
```

- `-t` uses the specified char as a field separator
- `-k` defines a restricted sort key that has the starting position

See `man sort` for additional information.

Answer (score 2):

That `cat-grep-cut-head` sequence can be replaced with `awk`

```
awk -v FS="," '/IM_SYS_TPS/{if(count++==10)quit;print $1,$4}' 
tps_info.edr.2018-01-15* | sort -t"," -k2
```

All good <kbd>:-)</kbd>

Comment: Should be: `:_)`. Solving problems bring tears to programmer's eyes.

Comment: Lol, I kinda agree to that pal. But that smiley for me means bit of relief `;-)`